# Automatic onepage checkout - quote issue

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I'm creating automated checkout feature, which will create few orders at once:

What's wrong with that?

This script let's say creates 4 different orders with different prodcuts, for different users, but problem lies here, each order created after first order has got subtotal and grand total of first order. How can I reset that?

Mage::app('default');

```
/**
 * Get the resource model
 */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

/**
 * Retrieve the read connection
 */
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM m4gsrepeated_orders WHERE execution <= CURDATE()';
$all_orders = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);


function addCartItems($products_array) {
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    foreach($products_array as $productw) {
        $sku = $productw[0]; 
        /** @var $productCollection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $productCollection = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter( 'sku', $sku );
        /** @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $product = $productCollection->getFirstItem();
        // you should have the product now, maybe it isn't even necessary to get the ID
        $product = $product->load($product->getId());   
        $cart->addProduct($product, $productw[1]);
    }       
    $cart->save();
}


foreach ($all_orders as $order) {
    //Set basic data
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setReservedOrderId(null);
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
    ->load($order['user_id']);

    // Set as Logged In and Clear Session
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)->renewSession();


    //Set up cart
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

    //get current cart items;s
    $i=1;
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $products_current[$i][0] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
        $products_current[$i][1] = intval($item->getQty());
        $i++;
    }
    $i=1;

    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');

    foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
        $cart->removeItem( $item->getId() );
    }

    $products_delayed = json_decode($order['items']);
    addCartItems($products_delayed);
    $cart->save();


    //LUUUTA CREATE ORDER

    # Get customer default shipping information
    $customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
    if ($customerAddressId){
        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
        $shippingAddress = $address->getData();
    }

    # Get customer default billing information
    $customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
    if ($customerAddressId){
        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
        $billingAddress = $address->getData();
    }
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    /*
    * One page checkout consists of following steps
    * (1) Customer login method aka Checkout method
    * (2) Billing information (address)
    * (3) Shipping information (address)
    * (4) Shipping method
    * (5) Payment information
    * (6) Order review, in short: DO THE ORDER
    */
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
    $checkout->initCheckout();
    $checkout->saveShippingMethod('excellence_excellence'); 

    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('excellence_excellence');

    $quote->getShippingAddress()->unsGrandTotal();      //clear the values so they won't take part in calculating the totals
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->unsBaseGrandTotal();

    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)->save();

    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();    //collect totals and ensure the initialization of the shipping methods

    $quote->collectTotals();

    //STEP(1)
    $checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');

    //STEP(2)
    $checkout->saveBilling($billingAddress, false);

    //STEP(3)
    $checkout->saveShipping($shippingAddress, false);

    //STEP(4)
    $checkout->saveShippingMethod('excellence_excellence'); 


    //STEP(5)
    $checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'pay'));

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('excellence_excellence');

    //STEP(6)
    /*
    * $checkout->saveOrder() returns array holding empty object
    * of type Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
    */

    try {
        $checkout->saveOrder();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage(); 
    }   

    //addCartItems($products_delayed);
    $cart->truncate();
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
    $customerAddressId = '';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is fixed:

That lied in checkout/session and customer/session which had to be cleared.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->clear();
```

That might help someone when resolving batch ordering solution with similar method.

Thanks,
Adam